# Always same resaut in javascript if

Tags: javascript

How can I fix this, I'm always getting <18 result I tried numbers 1-100 but result is text for <18 always

```
In HTML i have <p> with id="rezultat", input with id "godine" and buttno with id "btn"

JavaScript
let = document.getElementById("rezultat");
let dugme = document.getElementById("btn");
let god = document.getElementById("godine");

function myFunction() {

if (god >= 18){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
}
if (god <= 65){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
}
if (god < 18){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Imate premalo godina";
}
if (god > 65){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Imate previse godina";
}
}
```

Comment: Write in `if-else-if-else` ladders, after 1st if its not returning to the caller of this function

Comment: `god` is an HTMLElement. Not its value, and much less its *numeric* value.

Comment: You are not assigning the value properly. Do this 'let god = document.getElementById("godine").value; '

Comment: <input id="godine" type="number" > i have this in HTML and I'm trying to when I click button get text depends of number that I writed in that input but I'm do not getting correct text... Just tried 'let god = document.getElementById("godine").value; ', in this case I don't get any text

Comment: this is in html

Comment: <body>
    <h1>Prijava za maraton</h1>

    <form id="forma">
        <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ime">
        <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
        <input type="text" id="prezime">
        <label for="godine">Broj godina:</label>
        <input id="godine" type="number" >
        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" >Prijava</button>

      </form>

      <p id="rezultat"></p>      

</body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the last two in your function seem to be the important ones - too young or too old - start with those and, if the user is not one of those, they are in the right age group:

```
function myFunction() {
  if (god < 18) {
      document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Imate premalo godina";
  } else if (god > 65) {
      document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Imate previse godina";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
  }
}
```

So, if they are under 18, they are too young.  If they are over 65, they are too old.  Otherwise, they can sign up successfully.

Also, make sure that you are getting a number from the "godine" element - for example:

```
let god = parseInt(document.getElementById("godine").value);
```

Comment: Just tried, and I getting to young for every number ("Imate premalo godina")... This is file github.com/nemanja159/if

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that you are getting a number from the "godine" element?  I have added a bit to the bottom of my Answer to show a way to do that.  Otherwise, the "god" variable will be pointing to the element itself **not** the value.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, can you check github link?

Comment: That is your original code.  I have given you a way to update it and explained that you need to check that you have the element's value.  Try that first.

Comment: When i replace `let god = document.getElementById("godine");`with `let god = parseInt(document.getElementById("godine").value);` it doesn't return any text

Comment: It will if you move that line **INTO** your function as that is when it is needed.

Comment: Good!  You should flag my Answer as correct so that others know that you now have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let = document.getElementById("rezultat");
let dugme = document.getElementById("btn");
let god = document.getElementById("godine");

function myFunction() {
   let text = '';

   if (god >= 18){
     text = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
    } else if (god <= 65){
    text = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
    } else if (god < 18){
    text = "Imate premalo godina";
    }else if (god > 65){
    text = "Imate previse godina";
   }
  document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: always getting "Uspesno ste se prijavili" for any number

Comment: console the value of `god` inside the myFunction

Comment: i have this in html

Comment: <body>
    <h1>Prijava za maraton</h1>

    <form id="forma">
        <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ime">
        <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
        <input type="text" id="prezime">
        <label for="godine">Broj godina:</label>
        <input id="godine" type="number" >
        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" >Prijava</button>

      </form>

      <p id="rezultat"></p>      

</body>

Comment: We have to change the condition. Can you define your use cases?

Comment: I have input and there I need to type age, click a button, and depending on the age that I entered to get some text. This is the entire file https://github.com/nemanja159/if

Answer (score 0):

The  problem is that the tests are on the variable 'god' which actually is the HTML input element, not the value the user has typed in.

To get the value you need to use god.value

Try this

```js
let = document.getElementById("rezultat");//BTW this does nothing useful
let dugme = document.getElementById("btn");
let god = document.getElementById("godine");

function myFunction() {
if (god.value >= 18){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
}
if (god.value <= 65){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Uspesno ste se prijavili";
}
if (god.value < 18){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Imate premalo godina";
}
if (god.value > 65){
    document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = "Imate previse godina";
}
}
```

```html
<p id="rezultat"></p>
<input id="godine"/>
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: not working.. This is entire file https://github.com/nemanja159/if

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'not working'? It now tests against the right value, but your tests need to be organised better - go through each one, one by one to see what happens.